# gaze always execute even after PointExit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gaze-buttons

I have a problem about my gaze on VR . What I am trying to do is that gaze upon the button I want to select then hide the first gameobject parent then show the second gameobject parent . Now the second gameobject parent will be shown and when I try to gaze upon the back button it will show the first gameobject parent and hide the second gameobject parent . The problem occurs here, when I am trying to nothing and don't gaze on the buttons it automatically show my second gameobject parent and go back to first parent gameobject and hide and show and hide and show always.

```
public float gazeTime = 2f;
private float timer;
private bool gazedAt;

public Setting setting;

private void Start()
{

}

public void Update()
{
    if (gazedAt)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= gazeTime)
        {
            // execute pointerdown handler
            ExecuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
            timer = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}

public void PointerEnter()
{
    gazedAt = true;
    Debug.Log("PointerEnter");
}

public void PointerExit()
{
    gazedAt = false;
    Debug.Log("PointerExit");
}

//Method for going to setting
public void Setting()
{
    setting.ActivateSetting();
}
//Method for going back to main menu
public void GoBack()
{
    setting.GoBackToMainMenu();
}
```

Here's how my `Setting` code is setup

```
public GameObject setting;
public GameObject back; 

public void ActivateSetting()
{
    setting.SetActive(false);
    back.SetActive(true);
}

public void GoBackToMainMenu()
{
    back.SetActive(false);
    setting.SetActive(true);
}
```

What I want is that it will only show the gameobject parent if I gaze upon it.

Comment: Are `Setting` and `GoBack` called somewhere?

Comment: They're called on the EventTrigger @derHugo

Comment: How exactly? Both in `OnPointerDown` at the same time? Also why going through the `EventTrigger` at all? Instead of your complicated call to `ExecuteEvents.Execute` why not simply calling the according method directly?

Comment: Also make sure that `gazeTime` still has the value `2.0f` .. it might be different in the Inspector than in the script.

Comment: @derHugo how can I call my method sir If I don't gaze upon the buttons?

Comment: instead of `ExecuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);` simply do e.g. `GetComponent<Button>.onClick.Invoke();` or directly e.g. `setting.ActivateSetting();`

Comment: can you give an example sir on the `Getcomponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling the click once you reset the `timer` but you didn't reset `gazedAt`

=> the `Update` method did still run the timer and call the click again.

It seems that your `PointerExit` is not called at all and therefore the button never reset.

---

Instead of the `EventTrigger` I would strongly recommend to use the interfaces [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) and `IPointerExitHandler` like

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    //...

    public void OnPointerEnter()
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerExit()
    {

    }
```

---

I would actually not use `Update` at all but prefer a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Also don't use the complex call of `ExecuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);` instead use either `Getcomponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();` or call the method directly

```
private Button _button;

private void Awake()
{
    // Get the reference only once to avoid 
    // having to get it over and over again
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();
}

private IEnumerator Gaze()
{
    // wait for given time
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gazeTime);

    // call the buttons onClick event
    _button.onClick.Invoke();

    // or as said alternatively directly use the methods e.g.
    setting.ActivateSetting();
}

public void OnPointerEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("PointerEnter");

    // start the coroutine
    StartCoroutine(Gaze());
}

public void OnPointerExit()
{
    Debug.Log("PointerExit");

    // stop/interrupt the coroutine
    StopCoroutine(Gaze());
}
```

As you can see there is no need at all for the `timer` and `gazedAt` values so you can't forget to reset them somewhere. It also avoids that the method is called repeatedly.

---

If you don't want to use a `Button` at all you could also add your own [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) like

```
// add callbacks e.g. in the Inspector or via script
public UnityEvent onGazedClick;

// ...

onGazedClick.Invoke();
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if it hits the button even for a split second it will wait for 2 seconds to activate even if I changed the gaze to another button.

Comment: Actually this code is very useful I'll mark this as an answer though I'll be honest that it wasn't what I want. But it's very helpful

Comment: No .. it shouldn't activate at all since the routine is stopped when you exit the button

Comment: It doesn't stop sir.

Comment: Uhm okey.. How is `PointerEnter` and `PointerExit` called?

Comment: Your edit does basically the same but less efficient. I would prefer to not use the string version because if you rename the method than you allways have to remember also change that string. You also can not pass in parameter that easily